# Is it correct to pause/resume a long running Task (while(true)) with Monitor.Wait() and Monitor.Pulse()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following code, which acts as an async Consumer:

```
private readonly Object sync;

private async void ConsumeAsync()
{
    // The reason why I have an await here is to yield the control to the caller, e.g: if an exception happens inside the Listen method, it's being propagated and can be handled in caller codes.
    await Task.Run(() => this.Listen());
}

private void Listen()
{
    ...
    while (true)
    {
        lock (sync)
        {
            while (<blocking-condition>)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(sync);
            }
        }

        // Consuming happens here
    }
}

// Changing the blocking condition happens outside the infinite loop with proper Monitor.Pulse usage
```

My design concerns:

1. I have an async void fire-and-forget method which must be blocked if nothing to consume. Is it a proper approach?
2. Do I have to use the LongRunning option for the Task?
3. Do I have to use CancellationToken?
4. Am I propagating exceptions correctly to a higher level exception handler?

Comment: This can help. [Cooperatively pausing async methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/01/13/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods.aspx)

Comment: Best practise is to [avoid `async void` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) - as "When an exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task<T> method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an async void method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method started. " ...

Comment: But what if I use a BlockingCollection or another 3rd party collection (like a RabbitMQ shared queue) which can block its calling thread using Monitor.Wait inside the while (true) loop?

Answer (score 1):

Two of your four questions are too broad for this forum. Only you can decide whether this is "a proper approach" for your scenario. Likewise, the question of whether to use a `CancellationToken` or not depends on what features you need. If you need to be able to cancel the operation, that can be a good approach, but is not the only one and there's not enough detail here to know what would be best. Nor could you provide enough detail while keeping the question narrow enough for this forum.

Of course, if you don't need to be able to cancel the operation, the answer to that question is "no, you don't need to use `CancellationToken`" :).

As for the other two questions, only one has a clear answer:

2. "Do I have to use the LongRunning option for the Task?"

No, you don't *have* to. But it is strongly advised for tasks which are in fact long-running. This will help the task scheduling framework correctly manage your task's thread.

4. "Am I propagating exceptions correctly to a higher level exception handler?"

It's doubtful that you are. Since your `ConsumeAsync()` method is `async void`, you obviously cannot be waiting on it. The natural way to do this sort of thing would be to write the code more like this:

```
private Task ConsumeAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => this.Listen());
}

async Task SomeMethodSomewhereElse()
{
    try
    {
        await ConsumeAsync();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // An exception thrown from your long-running task will be caught here
    }
}
```

Note that the `ConsumeAsync()` method does not itself actually need to be `async`. You can just return the `Task` that was created, and will work exactly the same (well, more efficiently...but the main thing is just to not add the extra code that is completely unnecessary).

The way you've written it, you would have to go to a lot of extra work to catch the exception thrown (i.e. handle it from the `SynchronizationContext` directly). Maybe you did that, maybe you didn't. You didn't show that code, so I assume you did not.

Comment: Thanks for your brief answer. What's your opinion about using the Monitor.Wait to pause that Listen method?

Comment: If you're going to block the thread, `Monitor.Wait()` is as good a choice as any, assuming it serves your needs. That said, the method name `ConsumeAsync()` implies a producer/consumer pattern, for which the `BlockingCollection<T>` type is perfectly suited. You won't need any explicit synchronization at all if you use that class.